# Converting time-stamp to correct class in R

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I have timestamp data that is of the "factor" class. It looks as follows:
"193:00:11" ; where it is hours:minutes:seconds ...

I am trying to convert this to the right timestamp class so I can perform calculations on it (like determine the mean, max, minimum etc.,). I have tried using lubridate, and doing:
hhmmss(df1$time) ; but this does not work and just gives me the seconds back.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There is no standard class for times in R.  You can try package `chron`, which has an S3 time class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings/factors are always in this format, this will give the number of seconds elapsed. The data must be in a `character` vector.

```
#example data
tm <- c("193:01:11", "96:22:47", "1:01:01", "2:02:02")
tmm <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(tm,":"))),ncol=3, byrow=T)
tmm %*% c(3600, 60, 1)
```